# Deltaspike Data module: no bean matches the injection point

Tags: cdi, deltaspike

I am trying DeltaSpike Data Module on Wildfly i followed the things mentioned in the document, when I try to run a Servlet having a Repository i am getting a NullPointerException while using the repository

```
@Inject
private OrdersRepository orderRep;


 List<OrderDto> dao = orderRep.findByRetailer("MyRetail"); // NullPointer
```

Code

```
@Repository(forEntity = Order.class)
@MappingConfig(OrderMapper.class)
@EntityManagerConfig(entityManagerResolver = MyDBResolver.class)
public  abstract class OrdersRepository extends AbstractEntityRepository<OrderDto, String> {
@Query(named = Order.ORDER_BY_RETAILER, max = 1)
public abstract List<OrderDto> findByRetailer(String retailer); 
}
```

...

Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: Why you're using different class (OrderDto) in AbstractEntityRepository's generic? i.e., AbstractEntityRepository<OrderDto, String> instead of AbstractEntityRepository<Order, String>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `@Dependent` to your repository classes.

CDI 1.1 used in WildFly has implicit bean archives by default, i.e. candidate bean classes require a bean defining annotation.

Comment: thank you it works but i am now getting " Table "ORDERS" not found; SQL statement:" "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement"  for findAll  method.   I have mentioned @NoSql(dataFormat = DataFormatType.MAPPED,dataType ="orders")  In mongo  table name is in lower case.